# Append a sub-string at the beginning in a DataFrame instead of at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to extract a sub-string from `Name` and add that **in front** of `Address` but `cat` is by default adding it **to the end**.

My data:

```
Name                              | Address
Eleanor A. Martin #/222  Rhapsody | Street 32601 Florida
Ann K. Wagner                     | 3071 Half and Half Drive Hialeah FL 33012
```

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Eleanor A. Martin #/222  Rhapsody ','Street 32601 Florida'],['Ann K. Wagner','3071 Half and Half Drive Hialeah FL 33012']],columns=['Name','Address'])   

df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.cat(df['Name'].str.extract(r'#/(.*)'), sep=' ', na_rep = '').str.strip()
```

Current Result:

```
Name                              | Address
Eleanor A. Martin #/222  Rhapsody | Street 32601 Florida 222  Rhapsody
Ann K. Wagner                     | 3071 Half and Half Drive Hialeah FL 33012
```

Desired result:

```
Name                              | Address
Eleanor A. Martin #/222  Rhapsody | 222  Rhapsody Street 32601 Florida
Ann K. Wagner                     | 3071 Half and Half Drive Hialeah FL 33012
```

This is not working in my set (messing up different rows)

```
df['Address'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r'#/(.*)') + " " + df['Address']
```

How can I add the sub-string from `Name` in front of the string in `Address` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add parameter `expand=False` for `Series` from [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), add separator and replace missing values to empty string, last add second column:

```
df['Address'] = (df['Name'].str.extract(r'#/(.*)', expand=False).add(" ").fillna('') + 
                 df['Address'])
```

Alternative:

```
df['Address'] = ((df['Name'].str.extract(r'#/(.*)', expand=False) + " ").fillna('') + 
                 df['Address'])
```

---

```
print (df)

                                 Name  \
0  Eleanor A. Martin #/222  Rhapsody    
1                       Ann K. Wagner   

                                     Address  
0        222  Rhapsody  Street 32601 Florida  
1  3071 Half and Half Drive Hialeah FL 33012
```

Comment: Many thanks again Jezrael. Sometimes I'm close but looking for the solution for hours

Answer (score -1):

Similar to your original solution:

`df['Address'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r'#/(.*)').str.cat(df['Address'], sep=' ', na_rep = '').str.strip()`